# Need help solving error when deploying Next JS app to GITHUB pages

Tags: next.js, typeerror, sanity, parse-error

Receiving a type error: Failed to parse URL at path /

[image: The error]

[image: Api route]

[image: utils file]

I have tried adding secrets/environment variables from the .env file to github pages. I also have tried to replace all API routes with the absolute URL "localhost:300/api/...".